# C# create List<T> in initialization vs get

Tags: c#, optimization

I was wondering what is the best method to create a list in a certain object.

1) DefA "always" occupies memory beforehand even if it is never called, right?

2) DefB will "always" have to check for the null condition or does the compiler optimizes this?

3) Is there a better way to implement this?

Thanks

```
private  List<A> _defA = new List<A>();
public List<A> DefA
{
    get { return _defA; }
}

private List<B> _defB;
public List<B> DefB
{
    get
    {
        if (_defB == null)
            _defB = new List<B>();

        return _defB;
    }
}
```

Comment: How would you expect the compiler to optimize out the check in the second case? As for "better" - that really depends on whether you care about the laziness. Do you have concrete evidence that *either* the unnecessary list *or* the null check actually has a signficant impact on your app?

Comment: Think that A and B can behave differently in case of multithreaded acess to property.

Comment: This is a nice question for [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Is this a simplified example of a more complicated case, or are you actually worried about a single, empty `List`?

Comment: It's `memory overhead` vs `code complexibility/time`. I think time is more expensive. Less complexibility is better.

Answer (score 4):

Because I think both options will not affect on performance of your application, my suggestion to choose one which keep code cleaner

Use Lazy type - [Lazy on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331(v=vs.110).aspx)

From MSDN about Lazy initialization:

> By default, Lazy objects are thread-safe. That is, if the
>   constructor does not specify the kind of thread safety, the Lazy
>   objects it creates are thread-safe. In multi-threaded scenarios, the
>   first thread to access the Value property of a thread-safe Lazy
>   object initializes it for all subsequent accesses on all threads, and
>   all threads share the same data. Therefore, it does not matter which
>   thread initializes the object, and race conditions are benign.

So in your case

```
private  Lazy<List<A>> _defA = new Lazy<List<A>>(() => new List<A>());

public List<A> DefA
{
    get 
    { 
        return _defA.Value; 
    }
}
```

In addition this approach will tell your intents to other developers who may work with your code.

Answer (score 1):

In this specific example, the delayed (lazy) instantiation might save a few milliseconds on startup; but at the risk of issues in a multi-threaded scenario.

Say two threads call DefB (Get) almost simultaneously - they might end up setting _defB twice, instead of the once that you intend.

_defA will always take the memory of an empty list, as I understand it, yes - so you'll save some memory the second way if it's not called - but it does make the code MUCH harder to understand. Also, what if a local piece of code doesn't call the accessor method, but just does _defB.Add() or whatever? (which might not be deliberate now, but because it's more complex it's easy to forget/miss in the future)

Comment: affix: And for the second one, you always need to check on `null` before using the List instance. Which makes the code less readable.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, don't optimize something that doesn't need optimizing.

If you're creating thousands or millions of the object that contains that property, and this property is seldom used and thus seldom needed, then yes, adding lazy on-demand initialization is probably a good idea. I say probably because there may be other performance-related issues as well.

However, to answer your specific questions, other than "what is the best way":

1. The initialization of `_defA` will construct a `List<A>` object even if the property is never used, that is correct.
2. The getter method of `DefB` will always do the null check, that is also correct. The compiler cannot optimize this away.

As for "better way"? That part of the question falls into the "primarily opinion-based" close option here on Stack Overflow. It depends largely on what you determine is better:

1. More expressive syntax (shorter code)
2. Less memory spent (option B)
3. Less code in the getter (option A)

I can give you an *alternative* to the syntax in option A:

```
public List<A> DefA
{
    get;
} = new List<A>();
```

This syntax is available in Visual Studio 2015 with C# 6 (even if you compiler for older .NET runtime versions) and is called Auto-property initializer.

The compiler will automagically create the backing field for you (the `_defA` equivalent) and mark it read-only, so *feature-wise* this is 100% identical to option A, it's just a different syntax.